# Hessian of Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, optimization, hessian

I have a ridge regression problem $$f(W) = \frac{1}{2} ||XW - Y||_2^2 + \lambda W^TW $$

I want to find the smoothness parameter of the function (the $L$ such that $f$ is $L$-smooth). For quadratic functions, this apparently is the largest eigenvalue of the Hessian. How do I get the Hessian of this function?

I tried solving and got $X^TX + 2\lambda I$. Is this correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix might help...

Comment: @jbowman I edited my post. Can you check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiating it once, we get $$\nabla f(W) = X^T(XW-Y)+2\lambda W$$

Hence the hessian is indeed $X^TX+2\lambda I$

Suppose the SVD of $X=U\Sigma V^T$, then $X^TX=V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T$, $X^TX+\lambda I =V(\Sigma^T\Sigma+\lambda I )V$.

Hence you just have to compute the largest singular value of $X$, square it and add $\lambda$ to it.

Alternatively, compute the largest eigenvalue of $X^TX$ directly and add $\lambda$ to it.